# Assembly language linker error

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

I am running OS/X 10.8 and Xcode 5.1.1 on my Mac and can't seem to get any basic assembly language to compile. When compiling from the command terminal I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file proj2.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): proj2.o
        Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
          "_main", referenced from:
             implicit entry/start for main executable
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone explain this error to me, and how to fix it?

I compile, link, and run with these commands:

```
nasm -f elf -l proj2.lst proj2.asm    
gcc -o proj2 proj2.o
./proj2.o
```

My code:

```
SECTION .data
msg: db "Hello world", 10,0 ; this is the message
yes db '6', 10, 0
no db '-1', 10, 0

SECTION .text
extern printf
global main

compare:    
    mov edi, [esp+4]
    mov ecx, [esp+8]
    mov eax, [esp+12]

    repne scasb;
    mov eax, 0
    setz al
    ret

found:
    jmp displayYes

displayYes:
    push yes    
    call printf 
    mov eax, 0
    leave 
    ret

displayNo: 
    push no
    call printf 
    mov eax, 0
    leave 
    ret

main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push dword 'w'
    push dword 10
    push msg
    call compare

    test eax, eax ; if letter equals 'w' set condition to zero 
    jnz found 

    push no 
    jmp displayNo
```

**UPDATE**

If I *compile* with:

```
nasm -f macho proj2.asm
```

I get this new error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file proj2.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): proj2.o    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You should provide the command used to produce `proj2.o` and also the source code if applicable.

Comment: @Jester Ok i added that

Comment: mac does not use elf format. Since your code is 32 bit apparently, you should try `nasm -f macho32` and `gcc -m32`. Also you might have to add underscores to global symbols such as `_main` and `_printf`.

Comment: nasm: fatal: unrecognised output format `macho32' - use -hf for a list

Comment: What's your nasm version? Also try `-f macho` then, and of course look at the list produced by `-hf`.

Comment: @Jester NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Jan 15 2014

Comment: @Jester update in post

Comment: You forgot to do the other things I have told you (to use `gcc -m32` and to add an underscore).